# Want to Understand the performance of join in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

There are different types of join in mysql like below:

```
1.JOIN
2.LEFT JOIN
3.RIGHT JOIN
4.INNER JOIN
5.LEFT OUTER JOIN
6.RIGHT OUTER JOIN
```

And i want to know which one perform better in query. And how we decide that this one suitable for this query. As JOIN and INEER JOIN fetch same data.In this case which one suitable.

Comment: `JOIN` is a synonym for `INNER JOIN`, all other Join operations are distinct and should be used depending on your requirements. Performance should not be a consideration provided you have correct indexes and aren't worrying about multi-million-row tables.

Comment: okay thanks. If my query took 14 seconds then its not good right?

Comment: Correct, it sounds like you're performing a JOIN on tables without an index for the joined columns.

Comment: okay let me check. Can i apply index if its not foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will repeat what @Dai said in the comments, joins should be used based on which operation you need, not on performance.  The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins) cover what the different types of joins are.  In particular I like [this visual explanation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins).

Analyzing why a query is slow is usually done with [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html).  It will tell you the plan for the query and you can determine things like if its doing a full table scan and what rows might need to be indexed.  [Here is a good writeup of how to use an EXPLAIN](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/).